# The sound made when eating

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a few people around me that are really loud eaters.  I'm not telling them to be quiet while eating, of course - these aren't my children, but I digress.

What the the word for the sounds made when eating?

Comment: This isn't what you're asking, but are you familiar with the term *misophonia*? Here's an interesting [*New York Times* article.](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/09/06/health/06annoy.html?_r=0)

Comment: There's no need for one, since polite people either make no sound, or don't mention any sounds that might occur.

Comment: @Raj, Looks like "nom nom nom" is often used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- ***munch*** *generally noisy eating, lots of saliva is involved and the person forgets to close their mouth -- not attractive.*
- **crunch** *a sound usually associated with eating crisps (BrEng), chips (AmEng) or a juicy crisp apple*
- ***slurp*** *the sound you make when eating liquids, especially true for soups or sucking a soft drink through a straw.*

Comment: Thank you @Mari-Lou A, but don't you think "smacking" is the most usual word to be used when someone is eating food when they are making an unpleasant noise often with their mouth open (as "slurping" and "crunching" have their own specific usuages)?! Isn't it a better choice than "munching"? If not, how they differ?

Comment: @A-friend you *smack* your **lips** if something is particularly delicious. The sound is not from eating or masticating food. The OP was looking for a more derogatory term. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/smack_1?q=smack scroll until idioms

Answer (score 4):

My girlfriend likes "nom, nom, nom"
I use "chomp" and "snarf"

Answer (score 4):

Lots of words are used for both the *action* of eating noisily, and the *sound*...

> [gobble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gobble), [chomp](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chomp), [champ](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/champ), [guzzle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/guzzle), [slurp](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slurp), etc.

...but I don't know any word that specifically and only refers to the sound, not the action. *Gobbling, chomping*, etc. can be either how someone eats, or the sound they make when eating like that.

Note that the last two verbs in my list are more often used of people noisily consuming *liquids*, but here are a few dozen written instances of [he slurped his noodles](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slurped%20the%20noodles%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22slurped%20his%20noodles%22&tbm=bks) showing that's not always the case.

Comment: If your kids are turkeys gobble is perfect.

Comment: @RyeBread: Ornithologically speaking, I tend to refer to mine as [gannets](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gannet). It's not so much that they're noisy eaters - just that they'll eat [a lot of] *anything, anywhen*.

Answer (score 1):

Gustation.  While gustation does not by itself denote the noises to which you refer, but only to the tasting of food, your friends apparently taste their food a little louder than you do, much to your annoyance and chagrin.

Then there is the following from "Champing at the bit vs. chomping at the bit" (see http://grammarist.com/usage/champing-chomping-at-the-bit/):

"One definition of bit is a metal mouthpiece used for controlling a horse, and one definition of **champ** is to bite or chew noisily. These are the senses meant in the idiom *champing at the bit*, which refers to the tendency of some horses to chew on the bit when impatient or eager. In its figurative sense, it means to show impatience while delayed, or just to be eager to start.

"The idiom is usually written chomping at the bit, and some people consider this spelling wrong. But **chomp** can also mean **to bite or chew noisily** (though chomped things are often eaten, while champed things are not), so chomp at the bit means roughly the same as champ at the bit.

"In fact, chomp, which began as a variant of champ, is alive in English while the biting-related sense of champ is dead outside this idiom, so it’s no wonder that chomping at the bit is about 20 times as common as champing at the bit on the web. Champing at the bit can sound funny to people who aren’t familiar with the idiom or the obsolete sense of champ, while most English speakers can infer the meaning of chomping at the bit.

"Still, if you’re writing for school or for readers who are versed in English, champing at the bit is probably the safer choice."

Comment: The terms "gustatory sounds", "gustatory noises", or "sounds of gustation" might fit best with what the OP wants.

Comment: But not in one word.  That's why I said gustation does not denote noises.  I understand your point, however.  Don

Answer (score 1):

Well if we are eating loudly at the table my grandma might say, "Quit **smacking** your lips and chew your food.  You boys sound like a group of cows."

Comment: I'm more used to someone "smacking his lips" in *anticipation of eating*, rather than while actually eating. As per [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/smack-your-lips) definition: *to close and open your mouth loudly **to express a strong wish to eat something you like a lot***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You are right for sure.  When you are waiting to do something it is "smacking at the bit".  (but you can say the phrase "chomping at the bit" too) It is a phrase I have heard at least a thousand times when we were eating too loud.  And it does sound like your lips are smacking.

Comment: @ RyeBread: That must be a localised usage. Neither I nor Google Books have any knowledge of ["smacking at the bit"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22smacking+at+the+bit%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). But GB claims over 25,000 instances of ["**champing** at the bit"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22champing+at+the+bit%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which is the version I'm familiar with.

Comment: Something I didn't know until just now is that *chomping at the bit* is a [more recent US usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=champing+at+the+bit%2Cchomping+at+the+bit&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=). In the UK it's still normally [*champing at the bit*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=champing+at+the+bit%2Cchomping+at+the+bit&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)